# How to debug Playwright e2e tests in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, e2e-testing, playwright

I have 3 stages for my application so far: `staging`, `testing (e2e)`, `production`.

[image]

- The `staging` and the `production` stages are a classical release pipelines.
- The `testing` stage uses the same pipeline agent as the `staging` stage and therefore runs on the same server. But it doesn't uses any artifacts, it just runs e2e tests on the public url through which the `staging` server is accessible.

When I connect myself via ssh and run manually `sudo npx playwright test --browser=all` inside the e2e folder, it starts like this and then finishes without any error messages:

```sh
Using config at /home/user/frontend/tests/e2e/playwright.config.js
Running 3 tests using 1 worker
```

But when I do the same thing within the pipeline (1. go to e2e folder, 2. run the test with the same command), I get a meaningless error and I don't know what to do with it.

```sh
2021-09-20T07:33:19.4386925Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-09-20T07:33:19.4423536Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /opt/vsts-agent-linux/_work/_temp/d25bd1f8-b4aa-4f03-baa9-632f7181bc85.sh
2021-09-20T07:33:50.0893773Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks more like an configuration issue on Azure DevOps side and not like a Playwright Test issue. Could you provide us your configuration?

Comment: @MaxSchmitt What kind of info in terms of configuration do you need?